# Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, object given While Saving One to Many Relationship forms

Tags: php, symfony, orm, symfony-forms, doctrine-extensions

i have one to many relationship between my user and roles. while creating a new user i have render all the roles from roles entity and render it on with create user form. after putiting user info and selecting roles. when inserting into the db it says
`Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, object given`

Below is my code.

**User Entity**

```
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="PNC\PermissionsBundle\Entity\Roles", mappedBy="users", cascade={"persist"})
     * @var ArrayCollection $role
     */
    private $role;
/**
     * @return ArrayCollection A Doctrine ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getRole()
    {
        return $this->role;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $role
     */
    public function setRole(ArrayCollection $role)
    {
        foreach($role as $rol)  {
            $rol->setUsers($this);
        }
        $this->role = $role;
    }

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->roles = new ArrayCollection();

    }
```

**Roles Entity:**

```
  /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="role")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $users;
/**
     * Set Users
     *
     * @param \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection $users
     * @return Roles
     */
    public function setUsers(ArrayCollection $users)
    {
        $this->users = $users;
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * Get users
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getUsers()
    {
        return $this->users;
    }
```

**and the form:**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('firstname','text',array(
            'label' => ucfirst('First Name *'),
            'attr'=> array(
                'class' => 'form-control',
                'autocomplete' => 'off'
            )))
             ->add('role', 'entity', array(
                 'class' => 'PNCPermissionsBundle:Roles',
                 'property' => 'role',
                 //'choice_list' => new SimpleChoiceList($optionArray),
                 'multiple' => true,
                 'expanded' => true,
                 'attr'=> array(
                     'class' => 'minimal',
                     'style' => 'position: absolute; opacity: 0;'
                 )
             ))
......
        ->add('save', 'submit', array(
            'attr' => array('class' => 'submit'),
            'label' => "Save"
        ))
        ;
    }
```

**and the controller:**

```
 public function newAction(Request $request){

        $basePath = $request->getScheme().'://'.$request->getHost().$request->getBaseUrl();
        $user = new User();
        $form = $this->createForm(new UsersType(), $user, array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('pnc_permissions_user_add'),
            'method' => 'POST',
        ));
        if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST')
        {
            $form->handleRequest($request);
            if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $factory = $this->get('security.encoder_factory');
                $encoder = $factory->getEncoder($user);
                $password = $encoder->encodePassword( $user->getPassword() , $user->getSalt());
                $user->setPassword($password);
                $em->persist($user);
                $em->flush();
                $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('notice', 'New user created successfully.');
                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('pnc_permissions_user_index'));
            }
        }
        return $this->render('PNCPermissionsBundle:Users:add_user.html.twig', array(
            'userForm' =>$form->createView(),
        ));
    }
```

New to symofny, unable to figure out the error. Plus i am using fos user bundle also. and on error page it says this;

```
Stack Trace
in vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/FOS/UserBundle/Model/User.php at line 142   -
            return $this;
        }
        if (!in_array($role, $this->roles, true)) {
            $this->roles[] = $role;
        }
```

Comment: be specific at which line the error is pointing to..

Comment: @ManojSalvi see the updated question.

Comment: var_dump the $this->roles ,   it is saying it is an object,   not an array, perhaps its a persistantcollection ?    just dump it,  so you atleast know what it actually is

Comment: still the same thing..

Comment: i put `exit(\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump(var_dump($this->roles)));`

Answer (score 3):

use this instead :

```
if (!$this->roles>contains($role)) {
        $this->roles[] = $role;
    }
```

in_array for array and **contains** for **ArrayCollection**